# Add only top level folder with git sparsecheckout

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I'm versioning only a repo folder with git sparsecheckout. I followed the instructions on [this](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) blog. I already had the repo, so what I did was:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true

echo api/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

It worked, but it also added other `api` folders inside the project, but I only want to add the top level `api` folder, not all `api`folders in the project.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Try adding this -> `./api/`

Comment: Noup, it didn't work.

Comment: My mistake. `/api/` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm using /api/ should work.

The [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) command is using a pattern format explained in [`git read-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout), where a leading slash references the root folder directory.
See an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36660903/6309).