# Git sparse checkout to only honor a folder at the root of the repo?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

We have a repo with a bunch of projects. I am only concern with the "oracle" project within the repo. However, upon pulling down the codebase, I found subdirectories called "oracle" within other folders. Is there a way to only grab the parent folder that matches?

```
git init <repo>
cd <repo>
git remote add -f origin <url>

git config core.sparseCheckout true

echo "oracle/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

## Output

```
#ls -l
  oracle
  directory123
  directoryabc

#find . | grep "oracle"
  directory123/sub1/sub2/oracle
  directoryabc/sub1/sub2/sub3/oracle
```

Comment: If the `oracle` project is at the root of your repo, I've got a feeling that writing `/oracle/` instead of `oracle/` should do the trick.

Comment: Well damn that works! You can submit as an answer if you like and I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By writing `oracle/` to `$GIT_DIR/info/sparse-checkout`, you're telling your Git repo to only populate the working directory with files (if any) *whose parent directory is called "oracle"*. Directories

```
oracle/
directory123/sub1/sub2/oracle/
directoryabc/sub1/sub2/sub3/oracle/
```

all satisfy this condition.

If you want to restrict the [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout) to the `oracle` directory that is *at the root* of your Git repo, you need to write, not `oracle/`, but `/oracle/` (note the leading forward slash) to `$GIT_DIR/info/sparse-checkout`.